# Are properties passed when you segue an object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, segue

I have an object that I want to segue between two MVC's. Do the properties in the first MVC get segued along with the object or is it only the methods. IE: if I have an int property with the value 5 and then perform a segue passing the object. Will my new MVC have access to this property and the value 5? or will it only have access to the passed objects methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are not passed or set on the destination viewController in a segue. If you want your destination viewController to use an object (instance of a class) or some simple variable, you must define that property in your destination viewController class and then set it in `prepareForSegue:` For example, in the code bit below, the destination viewController has a property 'sectionToShow' and the setter for that property is being called.

Another approach is to define a delegate for the destination viewController and set it in the same way. Then the destination viewController can call the methods and access the properties of the delegate.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    NSString* identifier = segue.identifier;

    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"userGuideSegue_home"]){
        UserGuideViewController* vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        [vc setSectonToShow:@"Home Screen"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Sadly, properties don't magically get passed through segues on their own (yet).

What you should do instead is override `prepareForSegue:sender:` in your view controller. Then you can access the destination view controller with `[segue destinationViewController]`. Once you have a reference to the view controller, you can set its properties.